# What is the best hair style for a fictional temple guard/warrior?

Tags: hair

A few of my friends and I are working on a project (in the star wars universe), and the character I am playing as is a witch from dathomir (not a nightsister). I have short, thick hair and I am having trouble finding hair styles that look like they belong in the star wars universe, while being practical to my characters combat filled life. Any and all input would be wonderful, as I am really stumped. (I'm honestly thinking of getting extensions to make my life a little easier.)

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. We don't answer questions which cannot be objectively evaluated, and the best hair style is all about personal tastes. You can find more info in the [help]

Comment: Although this is purely opinion-based, one would think that the best fashion choice for a temple Guardian would be to prioritize avoiding what could be advantageous for an opponent. So that the hair doesn't get in the way, I'd suggest either keep it cut very short like we saw with many clones in the 2008 series or if you want it long go with padme's choice on ep 2, as her hair is tied close to her head and behind it (you could tie it in a way to help protect the back of your neck, but keep it close to the head).

Comment: I suggest this be moved to https://movies.stackexchange.com/ .  Or Valxina you could ask it again there.  It is a specific question about the Star Wars universe and I am sure an individual with enough knowledge of that universe to answer would be delighted to do so.

Comment: If you want practical, I'd recommend taking a look at the military and going with a buzz cut. If you want Star Wars, the Night Witches of Dathomir are known for their hoods, so you can eschew the hair style entirely.